# Disable Scrollbar in NERDtree with MacVim

Tags: plugins, vim, macvim, nerdtree

I have been able to fully disable scrollbars in MacVim. However, when I startup NERDtree, NERDtree brings up a scrollbar of its on the left. How can I disable NERDtree's scrollbar?

Thank you in advance. I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Use the following:

```
:set guioptions-=L
```